# Laravel: How to give each user different landing pages depending on their id

Tags: php, laravel

I am using the basic laravel `auth` login and registration code. I just added more functionality to the form. I am trying to make each user, as they log in, to be redirected to their own different pages depending on what account type they are. Right now each user is redirected to the home blade on login. how can i change this so they are redirected to each user's custom page? below is my code:

**add user blade**

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <div class="container" style="width:60%">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">Add New User</div>
            <div class="card-body">
                {!! Form::open(['action'=>'UserAccountsController@store', 'method'=>'POST']) !!}
                    @csrf
                    <div class="form-group row justify-content-center">
                        {{Form::label('acctyp', 'Account Type',['class'=>'col-md-2'])}}
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            {{Form::select('acctyp',['Adm'=>'Admin','Rcd'=>'Records','Hod'=>'H.O.D','Tch'=>'Teacher','Std'=>'Student'],null,['placeholder'=>'Choose Account...','class'=>'form-control'])}}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row justify-content-center">
                        {{Form::label('name', 'Name',['class'=>'col-md-2'])}}
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            {{Form::text('name','',['placeholder'=>'Name','class'=>'form-control'])}}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row justify-content-center">
                        {{Form::label('surname', 'Surname',['class'=>'col-md-2'])}}
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            {{Form::text('surname','',['placeholder'=>'Surname','class'=>'form-control'])}}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row justify-content-center">
                        {{Form::label('gender', 'Gender',['class'=>'col-md-2'])}}
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            {{Form::select('gender',['F'=>'Female','M'=>'Male','O'=>'Other'],null,['placeholder'=>'Choose Gender...','class'=>'form-control'])}}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row justify-content-center">
                        {{Form::label('dob', 'Date of Birth',['class'=>'col-md-2'])}}
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            {{Form::date('dob','',['class'=>'form-control'])}}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row justify-content-center">
                        {{Form::label('email', 'E-mail Address',['class'=>'col-md-2'])}}
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            {{Form::email('email','',['placeholder'=>'E-mail Address','class'=>'form-control'])}}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row justify-content-center">
                        {{Form::label('userid', 'User I.D',['class'=>'col-md-2'])}}
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            {{Form::text('userid','',['placeholder'=>'User I.D','class'=>'form-control'])}}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row justify-content-center">
                        {{Form::label('password', 'Password',['class'=>'col-md-2'])}}
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            {{Form::password('password',['placeholder'=>'Password','class'=>'form-control'])}}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row justify-content-center">
                        {{Form::label('cpassword', 'Confirm Password',['class'=>'col-md-2'])}}
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            {{Form::password('cpassword',['placeholder'=>'Confirm Password','class'=>'form-control'])}}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row justify-content-center">
                       {{Form::submit('Add User',['class'=>'btn btn-success'])}}
                    </div>
                {!! Form::close() !!}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready( function() {
            $('#userid').on('change', function() {
                $('#password').val($(this).val());
                $('#cpassword').val($(this).val());
            });
        });
    </script>
@endsection
```

**login controller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }
}
```

**add user conrtoller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;

class UserAccountsController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $accounts = User::all();
        return view('users.index')->with('accounts', $accounts);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('users.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'acctyp'=>'required',
            'name'=>'required',
            'surname'=>'required',
            'gender'=>'required',
            'dob'=>'required',
            'email'=>'required',
            'userid'=>'required',
            'password'=>'required',
        ]);

        $account = new User;
        $account->acctyp = $request->input('acctyp');
        $account->name = $request->input('name');
        $account->surname = $request->input('surname');
        $account->gender = $request->input('gender');
        $account->dob = $request->input('dob');
        $account->email = $request->input('email');
        $account->userid = $request->input('userid');
        $account->password = bcrypt($request->input('password'));
        $account->save();

        return redirect('/users')->with('success', 'New user successfully added!');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        $account = User::find($id);
        return view('users.show')->with('account', $account);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        $account = User::find($id);
        return view('users.edit')->with('account', $account);
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'acctyp'=>'required',
            'name'=>'required',
            'surname'=>'required',
            'gender'=>'required',
            'dob'=>'required',
            'email'=>'required',
            'userid'=>'required',
            'password'=>'required',
        ]);

        $account = User::find($id);
        $account->acctyp = $request->input('acctyp');
        $account->name = $request->input('name');
        $account->surname = $request->input('surname');
        $account->gender = $request->input('gender');
        $account->dob = $request->input('dob');
        $account->email = $request->input('email');
        $account->userid = $request->input('userid');
        $account->password = bcrypt($request->input('password'));
        $account->save();

        return redirect('/users')->with('success', 'User successfully updated!');
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $account = User::find($id);
        $account->delete();

        return redirect('/users')->with('success', 'User successfully removed!');
    }
}
```

Comment: in your login controller you can do something like `$this->redirectTo = auth()->user()->role() ."/profile"` inside of the constructor

Comment: I feel you should do your logic inside of your controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should follow the below steps for that:

In `LoginController.php`

Override this method `protected $redirectTo = '/home';`
So you need to remove the above code and add following code:

```
public function redirectTo(){


    $type = Auth::user()->acctyp; 


    switch ($type) {
        case 'type1':
            return '/YOUR PATH';
            break;
        case 'type2':
            return '/YOUR PATH';
            break; 
        default:
            return '/YOUR PATH'; 
            break;
    }
}
```

Remember to include class `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;` in `LoginController.php`

Comment: it gives me this error when i try logging in `Trying to get property 'name' of non-object`.

Comment: @ProvidenceMoyo Above code is only a demo for your question. You should set your own logic. Like, Have you a role for users?

Comment: not yet. i might implement roles later on. but this has helped. its no longer giving the error. thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You can define a `redirectTo` method on your `LoginController` and return the path you want them redirected to:

```
protected function redirectTo()
{
    // do your logic to decide where to go and return a path

    $user = $this->guard()->user();

    if ($user->acctyp == 'something') {
        return route('something.dashboard');
    }
    ...
}
```

When using the `redirectTo` method, the default setup will try to redirect them to a "intended" URL and fallback to what you return from `redirectTo`. (Intended would be where they were trying to reach before the `auth` middleware redirected them to the login page)

If you want full control over the response you can override the `authenticated` method on `LoginController`, which comes from the `AuthenticatesUsers` trait, to return the response you would like:

```
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    // do your logic here and return a redirect
    // to where you want them to go to

    if ($user->acctyp == 'something') {
        return redirect()->route('something.dashboard')
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: and how exactly can i write the logical statements for it?

Comment: that is for you to do, it is your application and your logic ... i dont know the logic you need to decide what type goes where, etc

Comment: i totally understand. was hoping for a basic framework to point me in the right direction as  am new to laravel.

Comment: @ProvidenceMoyo updated with how to use the user in the method and return something, not sure what the needs of your logic are though, hopefully it helps a little